# Showing the Prompt on loading and store the value to greet the User every time he opens the HomePage

Tags: javascript, html, prompt, sessionstorage

I'm trying to ask the Users "What's your name" using a prompt message to get its name. Then, greeting the user with a welcome message based on the current time.
So far, I could show the message only by clicking a button.
What I wanted to do is asking first for the name and, once got the Username, show the message directly when the HomePage is loaded.

This is the HTML:

```html
 <form> 
    <input id="show_button" class="button" type="button"   value="Hey! Click Me! I know you!" onclick="greet(), salutoTempo()" /> 
</form>
```

And this is the JavaScript Code:

```js
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();   
var saluto;

   
if (hourNow > 17) {   
  saluto = "Good evening"
} else if (hourNow > 11) {
  saluto = "Good afternoon"
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
  saluto = "Good morning"
} else {
  saluto = "Welcome to Wolf the Barber!"
}

var el = document.getElementById("greeting");





function salutoTempo(){
   document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = saluto + " ";
}




function greet(){
   name = localStorage.getItem("name");
   if (name == null || name == "null"){
     alert("Hi, Stranger!");
     name = prompt("What is your name?");
     localStorage.setItem("name", name);
     var greeting = document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = (greeting);
     var Username = document.getElementById("greeting1").innerHTML = (name + "!");
 } else {
     var greeting = document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = (greeting);
     var Username = document.getElementById("greeting1").innerHTML = (name + "!");
   } // end greet
 } // end function
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you can use `onload`attribute in `body` tag.  Additionally, call the function `salutoTempo`.

```
<html>
<body onLoad = "greet()">
 <form> 
    <input id="show_button" class="button" type="button"   value="Hey! Click Me! I know you!" onclick="greet(), salutoTempo()" /> 
</form>

<span id="greeting"></span>
<br>
<span id="greeting1"></span>

<script>
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();   
var saluto;

if (hourNow > 17) {   
  saluto = "Good evening"
} else if (hourNow > 11) {
  saluto = "Good afternoon"
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
  saluto = "Good morning"
} else {
  saluto = "Welcome to Wolf the Barber!"
}

var el = document.getElementById("greeting");

function salutoTempo(){
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = saluto + " ";
}


function greet(){
   name = localStorage.getItem("name");

   if (name === null || name === "null"){
     alert("Hi, Stranger!");
     name = prompt("What is your name?");
     localStorage.setItem("name", name);     
     document.getElementById("greeting1").innerHTML = (name + "!");
   } else {
     document.getElementById("greeting1").innerHTML = (name + "!");
   } // end greet
   salutoTempo();
} // end function
</script>
</body>
</html>
```